# javascript/jquery issue while clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

There's something going wrong with my java script code. I have a basic html page and this code

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid"> 
   <h3 class="myotherclass"><?php echo _("Some sentence"); ?></h3>
</div>
```

When I put this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div").click(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

the click on the div tag triggers the alert message, but when I put this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("h3").click(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

nothing is triggered. Could some explain this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in this case, you can use jquery's live() syntax : `.live( events, handler(eventObject) )`, see here [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You can also use on() syntax .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) ) because live is beginning being deprecated for the recent versions of jquery, see here[here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You should put your code within document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // ...
})
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. By the way, I am noticing that when I use my inspector to hover the zone and when I take the div-tag that contains 'h3' and which is highlighted by the inspector, and when I put this very div tag in the 'click-script', it works just fine. Is it a problem with my browser ?

Comment: @user1611830 What do you mean by _when I put this very div tag in the 'click-script'_? Using class selector? Which browser are you using? Do you see any error on the JS console?

Comment: it doesn't work either on chrome nor on safari. In fact the html part of code I put in my question, is in fact wrapped by a div with id "id", and this is this div that is detected by my inspector when hovering the zone. When I replace this div#id in my script, the click triggers the alert message.

Comment: @user1611830 Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net with your current markup?

Comment: indeed it works using jsfiddle but it doesn't work on my browser, though I cleaned the cache...

Comment: I think the problem is that the problem is coming from relative positioning : in fact there is a div tag coming after <div class="myclass" id="myid"> 
   <h3 class="myotherclass"><?php echo _("Some sentence"); ?></h3>
</div>, say <div id="otherid">...</div> When I use my inspector, the two divs 'myid' and 'myotherid' are hightlighted on upon each other. So how can I circumvent it ?

Answer (score 0):

did u wrap the code in ready handler.

```
$("document").ready(function(){})
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the problem is coming from relative positioning : in fact there is a div tag coming after <div class="myclass" id="myid"> 
   <h3 class="myotherclass"><?php echo _("Some sentence"); ?></h3>
</div>, say <div id="otherid">...</div> When I use my inspector, the two divs 'myid' and 'myotherid' are hightlighted on upon each other. So how can I circumvent it ?